# Selenium not working in firefox 23.0.1 (Mac and Windows)

Tags: selenium, crash

I have a client who had a script working and now stopped working. I run it in my computer and it works (i runned it on Linux and Windows). My client runned it on Mac and Windows.

I am new to Selenium, but the part of the code that crashes is where Selenium takes place, it gets the Firefox to open but not load the page. I think it migth be a problem with the webDriver of Selenium that must be updated.

I told him to install pip in his Mac and uninstall Selenium and reinstall it, is this how it is done in OS machines? Is there any issue related to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What Selenium version you are using? I suggest, use the updated version and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? If so, which?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had specify Selenium version and also which browser are you using and it's version too. But the behavior you described seems to be caused by having newer version of browser which the Selenium version you using doesn't support. So upgrading to newest version of Selenium (2.35) will likely make this problem disappear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, upgrade to newest version of Selenium.
The browser is Mozilla Firefox 23.0.1.
The problem with Selenium is that it is installed in a Mac Machine and I am helping this person through screen share. I am not used to Mac or Selenium so I don't know how to know what version of Selenium it has installed.

We tryed this:
easy_install pip
pip unistall selenium
pip install selenium

And that doesn't seem to work.

The portion of the code where it crashes is:
td = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id("propInfoZoneValue"))

Not exception

Comment: Ok, I can't help you with Mac but you we still don't know your version of Selenium which is probably the issue. And it would be really nice mentioning that you are using Python client

Comment: Ooops, sorry, my bad. Yes I am using Selenium with Python. I can't tell you what version of Selenium I have because I don't know how to see it. The issue is in Mac, I run it on Linux and works, but don't know how to see Selenium version even in Linux, if you can tell me how to know it at least in Linux that would be great.

I know I don't give a lot information but I was helping this client with the script and never used Selenium and newbie at Linux, so I don't know exactly how to look for Selenium vesion.